# gorethink inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, rethinkdb, nosql

I don't quit understand joins in RethinkDB and unfortunately there is very little documentation about it in German.

So i have a table 'categories' and there i have two docs:

```
{"id":1, "title":"Category 1"}
{"id":2, "title":"Category 2"}
```

Than i have a second table 'forums' and there i have three docs:

```
{"id":1, "title":"Forum 1", "categoryId":1}
{"id":2, "title":"Forum 2", "categoryId":1}
{"id":3, "title":"Forum 3", "categoryId":2}
```

What i want as an result is:

```
[{"id":1, "title":"Category 1", "forums":[{"id":1, "title":"Forum 1"},{"id":2, "title":"Forum 2"}]}, {"id":2, "title":"Category 2", "forums":[{"id":3, "title":"Forum 3"}]}]
```

I can't figure out how I can translate this JavaScript example (https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/#inner_join) to Go, since the arguments (marvelRow, dcRow) in the function need declarations in Go, but I have no idea which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first write it in JavaScript, then we will do it in Go, so you know how to do it next time.

What you want can easily do with either join or mapping. However, join will return a paird of match document, not in the nested way as you want. We can however map it like this:

```
r.table('categories')
  .merge(function(cat) {
    return {
      forums: r.table('forums').filter({categoryId: cat('id')}).without('categoryId').coerceTo('array')
    }
  })
```

Now let's move to Go lang.

```
package main

import (
    r "github.com/dancannon/gorethink"
    "log"
)

func main() {

    s, _ := r.Connect(r.ConnectOpts{
        Address:  "127.0.0.1:28015",
        Database: "test",
        MaxIdle:  10,
        MaxOpen:  10,
    })


    res, err := r.DB("test").Table("categories").Merge(func(doc r.Term) interface{} {
        return map[string]interface{}{
            "forums": r.DB("test").Table("forums").Filter(map[string]interface{}{
                "categoryId": doc.Field("id"),
            }).CoerceTo("array"),
        }
    }).Run(s)

    log.Println(err)

    var row interface{}
    for res.Next(&row) {
        log.Println(row)
    }
}
```

Everything is almost identical, except that in Go lang, you have to specified type. So you convert JS anonoymous function into Go lang anonymous function, but now everything will have type of `r.Term` most of time. You also have to specify return type, as we use `interface` in our case. JavaScript object becomes `map[string]interface{}` now.

In general, just go to this page https://github.com/dancannon/gorethink/wiki/Go-ReQL-command-reference and started to convert the JS one step at a time. It's almost one-one mapping except the type.

Comment: "Everything is almost identical, except that in Go lang, you have to specified type." jap that confused me the most and i am used to concrete types and in this driver, as you said, almost every time r.Term is used. Anyway thank you very much for your excellent answer! Now i can go on with work, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Note that the `filter` in this join does not utilize an index, and hence will become very slow as the tables become larger. I recommend replacing the `.filter({categoryId: cat('id')})` by `.getAll(cat('id'), {index: 'categoryId'})` and creating an index on the `categoryId` field.
I don't know how to use getAll in gorethink, but the gorethink documentation should have some info on that.

(Beachte dass der `.filter` Befehl in dem Join keinen Index benutzt, und daher bei grossen Tabellen sehr langsam werden kann. Besser waere es statt dessen `.getAll` mit einem sekundaeren Index zu benutzen.)

Answer (score 0):

SQL would be:

select c.id as cId,
f.id as fid
from categories c
inner join forums f on f.categoryId = c.id

Note: You can add other column from both tables.